# Delay when using ctrl + s keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, save, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-16.04

Whenever I try to save a file using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, there is a slight delay of half a second or so, which is really annoying me. Every other shortcut works in an instant, it is just the mentioned shortcut that is delayed.

I'm using a *Lenovo Ideapad 710s* with **Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what application (editor) are you using that shortcut?

Comment: In eclipse as well as gedit, so basically all of them, however I can't find the shortcut when I search for it in the ccsm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two shortcuts saved for Ctrl + s, therefore the delay. Holding the keys overrides the first shortcut.